# Mac as virtual machine guest: How to use multiple displays?

Tags: display, vmware, virtualization, parallels-desktop, virtualbox

I'm working on a test environment for testing Mac software. The plan is to use virtual machines (for example VMWare or Parallels) and install older versions as guest operating system, allowing me to test the software on older versions of OS X as well.

The one problem I have is that neither VMWare nor Parallels seem to work with multiple displays on a **OS X Guest** (I know they both work with Windows guests).

Is anyone using OS X as guest system, with multiple display support. If so, what is the visualization product and/or workaround?

Comment: have not done it myself but there seem to be at least one set of instructions:  http://kb.parallels.com/en/112121    and  http://kb.parallels.com/118806

Comment: @Joop: Those are install instructions, they have nothing to do with using multiple displays?